# How to solve this error when creating a Java Project

Tags: java, eclipse, project

I just started learning Java and now i got stuck with a Problem i can´t solve. I installed Eclipse and when i try to create a new java Project i get an Error: 
Could not load any rescource Bundle by: "com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.msg.DOMMessages".

Dont know whats wrong here. I tried to install another Version of Java, but that didn´t help. I am using Eclipse 4.4 for Win 64bit and Java Version 8 for Win 64bit too. Hope youn can help Thanks. Felix

Answer (score -1):

Try installing a 32 bit Eclipse. I know that sounds counterintuitive but I had no end of problems with the 64-bit Eclipse on my 64-bit Windows system. All those problems went away with 32-bit Eclipse.

Comment: Am i right that i have to use 32bit java then ? Thanks for your help !

Comment: I use 32-bit Eclipse with a 64-bit JDK and it works fine. I and my colleagues found problems only with 64-bit Eclipse.

Comment: OK Thanks... i just tried it and it works perfekt ! Now i can start learning java ... we will see